# Does honey, applied topically, cause your hair to go white?

Tags: hair, honey

I used to hear this from my friends: If you apply honey to your hair, your hair will turn white.

Is it true?

Comment: (To others wondering if this is notable, a quick Google search reveals it is a common question.)

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: What do you mean here by 'topically'?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I was trying to distinguish between eating honey and putting honey in your hair. The claim is the latter.